# Proper syntax for changing the value of an array in a 'for' loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

Okay, I just need to make sure I'm coding this correctly.  Please review the following when you have a moment:

```
int [] Counter_Event = new int [46];
for (int xCount = 0; xCount < Counter_Event.Length; xCount++)
    { Counter_Event[xCount] = Math.Round(xCount * 10000);}
```

With the above, it's tossing back a compilation error.  I'm probably not using proper syntax, but any perspective would help.

Comment: The compilation error message might have some information about your improper syntax.

Comment: It would help if you included the compilation error. The error I got running your code is on Math.Round, `CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Round(double)' and 'Math.Round(decimal)'`

Comment: if `xCount` is an int and 10000 is an int, why the need for the `Math.Round`?  They are already integers...

Comment: Syntax Errors - isnt that what *books* and *MSDN* are for?

Comment: @Plutonix Indeed. Even the tooltip on the syntax error explains *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: Hi all.  I apologize for posting an off-topic post without a clear problem statement.  It was a knee-jerk reaction to getting a cryptic 'Invalid token in class, struct or interface declaration.    I'll try a little better next time and spend more time researching it.

Comment: The code posted wont "toss back" that message.  Intellisense will report *ambiguous call` (see above) above while the Error window will more helpfully report *Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'...*

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Round()` requires a `demical` or a `double` as a parameter.

Something like this would work:

```
int[] Counter_Event = new int[46];
for (int xCount = 0; xCount < Counter_Event.Length; xCount++)
{ Counter_Event[xCount] = (int)Math.Round((double)xCount * 10000); }
```

Comment: Yeah, my problem was assuming Math.Round worked for int's.  Per other posts here, it's meant for double and decimal.  My bad.  I appreciate the conversion script above though.  If I need to go that route in the future, I'll reference it.  Thanks GBlock.

Answer (score 1):

You need to typecast the parameter of `Math.Round()` to either to `Double` or `Decimal`. Also, since your array `Counter_Event` is of type `int`, so again you have to cast the result of `Math.Round()` to `int` as `Math.Round()` return type is either `Decimal` or `Double`.

```
int [] Counter_Event = new int [46];
for (int xCount = 0; xCount < Counter_Event.Length; xCount++)
{ 
     Counter_Event[xCount] = (int)Math.Round((double)(xCount * 10000));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a dumb move on my part.  I completely spaced the type requirement by Math.Round.  Thanks for taking the time to post.